# How to Make HTML File Startup?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, routes

I have asp.net web api project. I have deleted **views** folder and added **index.html** root level file to the solution. 
Now when I visit the page `http://localhost:59305/` it displays `HTTP Error 403.14` - So html file is not opened.

How can I make the file to be opened first?

Comment: I wonder why you would create a Web API project and remove the views.

Comment: To create single page applications.

Comment: Then use the `Single Page Application` project template in Visual Studio (2013 for sure)

Comment: I have vs 2013, but SPA is not present. Do u mean service pack 1?

Comment: It should be there, check this: http://www.asp.net/visual-studio/overview/2013/creating-web-projects-in-visual-studio

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure the routing engine to ignore HTML files in the routing.

Use this in your `Global.asax.cs`:

```
RouteTable.Routes.IgnoreRoute("*.html");
```

Also try to set the default document in your web.config file. Add this:

```
<system.webServer>
  <defaultDocument>
    <files>
      <clear />
      <add value="index.html" />
    </files>
  </defaultDocument>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Still the same. Did u understand the question correctly? I want to show index.html as a default page.